# How to use IIF in Ms Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I want to write the query in MS ACCESS that executes based on condition.
Ex:

```
BEGIN
    IIF(@SaveType=1)  //For Insert
    THEN
     INSERT INTO EMP (ID,Name) VALUES (1,'Ajay');
    END

    IIF (@SaveType=2)  //For Update
    THEN
     UPDATE EMP SET Name='Vijay'
     WHERE ID=1
    END
 END
```

It is possible in SQL Server how can we use it in MS access?

Comment: Why can't you use simple `IF..ELSE`?

Comment: I am not sure, if it will actually work. Can you please tell how to use it, weather using IIF or IF?

Comment: Just replace `IIF` with `IF` in your query. This should work

Comment: Hi Andrey, This is not working, if you or any one can help me with different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    IF(@SaveType=1)  //For Insert
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO EMP (ID,Name) VALUES (1,'Ajay');
    END

    IF (@SaveType=2)  //For Update
    BEGIN
     UPDATE EMP SET Name='Vijay'
     WHERE ID=1
    END
```

Comment: I tried this, but its giving error like "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."

I am using MS Access 2010, and wrting the queries in Query Design window of Access.

Comment: Do you use this block inside procedure? If no, remove `BEGIN..END`. See my edited answer.

Comment: See my screen snapshot here http://postimg.org/image/7nw3frkil/ then you will get the clear idea.

Comment: Hey, you said you want this in SQL Server. This won't work with MS Access